# check an array whether this is sorted ascending/descending and they are increasing/decreasing with a fixed value

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

At first I want to check whether the array is sorted (ascending/descending) or not.Then I have to check whether the values are increasing/decreasing with a fixed value. like 1,2,3,...n.

Example: I have an array like `array[]={5,6,7,8,9}`
now I want to check whether the array[] is sorted or not.
Eventually I am able to check whether it is sorted or not. But mainly I want to know how to check the values of sorted(ascending/descending) array is increasing/decreasing by fixed value.

Here the values of the array is increasing by 1.

How to check this?

Comment: How about checking the difference between the first and second elements and then checking the difference between the second and third elements is the same, and so on?

Comment: also, simultaneously check that different is -ve , i.e a[i]-a[i+1] <0 , array is progressing in sorted order.

Answer (score 0):

You have to try to put some effort in coding and showing us the result so we can help you, also separate the two problems into two question..

Consider the following code as a start up to solve your problem:

1, take the difference between to each number in the `array`

2, add the difference inside a `Set` because in `Set` there is no duplicate data

3, if the `Set` contains only one `integer` then the array is sorted (ascending/descending) or all elements are equals

```
int[] intArray = { 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
// int[] intArray = { 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 };
// int[] intArray = { 9, 8, 7, 6, 5 };

Set<Integer> diffSet = new HashSet<>();
for (int i = 1; i < intArray.length; i++) {
    int diff = intArray[i] - intArray[i - 1];
    diffSet.add(diff);
}

if (!diffSet.isEmpty() && diffSet.size() == 1) {
    for (Integer integer : diffSet) {
        if (integer < 0) {
            System.out.println("The array is descending with fixed value of: " + integer);
        } else if (integer > 0) {
            System.out.println("The array is ascending with fixed value of: " + integer);
        } else {
            System.out.println("All elements in the array are equals");
        }
    }
}
```

Try To CONTINUE..